# Grouping strings with NULL values

Tags: mysql

I have a data set which contains many orders, each containing order items. I have logic looking for a specific order item..

```
order_id    status  
2933475 PAID    \N  
2933475 PAID    \N  
2933475 PAID    VALUE  
2933475 PAID    \N
```

The line item with VALUE could appear in any line item or not at all. When I group by order_id, I would like it to display VALUE if present for each order id, or \N if not present.

I thought that using `COALESCE()` would do this, but I am still getting NULL when grouping this order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your table/query structure, something like this may work:

```
select 
    order_id, 
    max(case when status = 'VALUE' then status else NULL end) as status
from table
group by order_id
```

Comment: thank you! didn't consider this because i thought NULL has no value to consider as a maximum. Guess I need to hit the books again!

Comment: No problem. NULLs just not used in aggregations - so an AVG of NULL, 1, and 2 is 1.5. It's useful to keep in mind! Make sure you mark this as the correct answer if it answers your question as well. Thanks :)